# How to get the DDL for Oracle object without extra characters

Tags: oracle, ddl

When using Oracle's dbms_metadata.get_ddl for getting DDL I see some extra characters, especially there are whitespace characters at very beginning of DDL script.
For example, if I create this sample procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST
IS 
BEGIN
 NULL;
END;
/
```

then dbms_metadata.get_ddl for this procedure returns extra newline and two space characters at very beginning:

```
select dbms_lob.substr(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE','TEST', USER), 37, 1 ) text
, dump(dbms_lob.substr(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE','TEST', USER), 37, 1 )) dump_text
FROM dual;

Result is:
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TEST"                                            
Typ=1 Len=37: 10,32,32,67,82,69,65,84,69,32,79,82,32,82,69,80,76,65,67,69,32,80,
82,79,67,69,68,85,82,69,32,34,84,69,83,84,34
```

As you can see there are `10,32,32,`, just before `CREATE OR REPLACE`.
Any idea how to get rid of these whitespaces? 
Also there are extra `"` around procedure name.

Comment: The double quotes are there to allow for the possibility that you created the procedure using a reserved word or containing a non-standard character.

Comment: Looking at the comments below and here, I think that you may be trying to do something in a slightly backwards fashion.  Can you explain what it is you want to achieve, then someone may be able to provide a better way to manage it.

Comment: I am guessing you may not be able to directly get rid of those 3 characters and double-quotes easily. These probably get added when xml to ddl transformation happens (dbms_metadata first generates xml and transforms it to ddl or sxml if requested). Because if you use dbms_metadata.get_xml, you don't see those characters, but you see them for get_ddl(). a substr(...get_ddl(),4) could fix that. You have to be careful about double quotes though.

Answer (score 1):

The following will get rid of the LF and 2 spaces using a function though it would probably be better/easier to do it in your text editor.

```
select 
   REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(
        dbms_metadata.get_ddl('FUNCTION','REMAP_SCHEMA', 'ETL'), 
      37, 1), CHR(10)||CHR(32)||CHR(32)||'CREATE','CREATE') text
   from dual
```

Obviously the first word that you are interested in keeping would need to be 'CREATE' for this to work. You could also use one of the REGEXP functions but I don't see that being any better/different to this method.
I'm also not sure why you particularly need to get rid of them.

Comment: I need to get exactly the same source code as it was created from. It will be compared semi-automatically externally for modifications, source versioning etc. I have the same thing for SQL Server and a lot of code. In Oracle, there would work user_source, but I look for solution with dbms_metadata.

Comment: You may need to get the first line using the above but wrap it in another REPLACE that replaces q'["]' with NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
set long 99999999
set pages 1000
exec dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
exec dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('<object_type>','<object_name>','<owner>') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

code as is, without any transformations or formatting:

```
  function getDDL(
      p_object_type varchar2
     ,p_object_owner varchar2
     ,p_object_name varchar2
  ) return clob is
      v_clob clob;
  begin     
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(
          lob_loc => v_clob
         ,cache   => true
         ,dur     => DBMS_LOB.CALL
      );
      for rec in (
          SELECT text
          FROM ALL_SOURCE
          WHERE NAME  = p_object_name
            AND OWNER = p_object_owner
            and type  = p_object_type
          order by line  
      ) loop
          DBMS_LOB.append(v_clob, rec.text);
      end loop;
      return v_clob;
  end getDDL;
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation why you think this piece of code does what the question author wants; code-only answers are not very helpful.